# My code line cannot work because of this error?

Tags: c#, winforms

So basically here is the problem, I have tried many ways to fix it but none of them worked ! Error is getting at this line :`Templist.Add((string)result["titre"];`.
`Templist` is the error !

```
private List<string> ReadNews()
{
    string SqlText = "SELECT * FROM nom_table"; 
    List<string> Templist; 
    MySqlConnection SqlConnection = new 
    MySqlConnection(TheConnectionString);
    MySqlCommand SqlCommand = new 
    MySqlCommand(SqlText,SqlConnection);


    MySqlDataReader result = SqlCommand.ExecuteReader();

    while (result.Read())
    {
        Templist.Add((string)result["titre"]);
    }

    return Templist;
}
```

Comment: What error? Post error message

Comment: `NullReferenceException` does happen when you try to access to properties or methods of null objects. Your `Templist` is not assigned anothing (so it is null)

Comment: If your `nom_table` table has too many columns or columns with large amount of data, your query will take too much time. Consider changing your select to `SELECT titre FROM nom_table`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 5):

Because you haven't initialized the `Templist`, until you initialize/assign an instance the declared variable(`Templist`) will be null, and you are not able to add something to `null` that is what the error message says. The code should be :

```
List<string> Templist =  new List<string>();
```

One more thing I would like to add here is the usage of `using` for proper disposal of the objects, and also specified `column names` instead for `*`. Consider the modified  snippets below:

```
private List<string> ReadNews()
{
    string SqlText = "SELECT titre FROM nom_table";
    List<string> Templist = new List<string>();
    using (SqlConnection SqlConnection = new MySqlConnection(TheConnectionString))
    {
        using (MySqlCommand SqlCommand = new MySqlCommand(SqlText, SqlConnection))
        {
            using (MySqlDataReader result = SqlCommand.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (result.Read())
                {
                    Templist.Add((string)result["titre"]);
                }
            }

        }
    }
    return Templist;
}
```

Comment: You could advice also against `select *`

Comment: You can remove the opening and closing braces of the first two using statements to reduce nesting.

Answer (score 4):

Your **`Templist`** should be initialized before use.
Change your declaration line to this:

```
List<string> Templist = new List<string>();
```

Answer (score 3):

**Templist** is null, you haven't created an instance yet. Initialize:

```
List<string> Templist = new List<string>();
```